# remove duplicate row inside the query

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY QUESID DESC)                     AS RowNum, 
       QUESID, 
       QUESCATEGORY, 
       QUESTION, 
       ID                                            OptionID, 
       OPTION_NAMES, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), ISNULL(RA.REVIEWERID, ''))ReviewerID, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), ISNULL(ANSWER, ''))       Answer 
FROM   EMP_TB_APP_QUESTIONMASTER QM 
       INNER JOIN EMP_TB_EOB_QUESTIONBANK_OBJECTIVEOPTIONS QO 
               ON QM.QUESID = QO.QUESTIONID 
       INNER JOIN EMP_TB_TRAN_PROBATION_REVIEW_FROM_ANSWERS RA 
               ON QO.ID = RA.QUESTIONID 
       INNER JOIN EMP_TB_TRAN_PROBATION_REVIEW_REVIEWER R 
               ON R.REVIEWERID = RA.REVIEWERID
```

I need to remove all repeated rows (No need to compare RowNum column)

Comment: Have you tried DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using distinct before adding the `ROW_NUMBER` to the query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY QUESID DESC) AS RowNum 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT QUESID, 
                        QUESCATEGORY, 
                        QUESTION, 
                        ID                                            OptionID, 
                        OPTION_NAMES, 
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), ISNULL(RA.REVIEWERID, ''))ReviewerID 
                        , 
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), ISNULL( 
                        ANSWER, ''))       Answer 
        FROM   EMP_TB_APP_QUESTIONMASTER QM 
               INNER JOIN EMP_TB_EOB_QUESTIONBANK_OBJECTIVEOPTIONS QO 
                       ON QM.QUESID = QO.QUESTIONID 
               INNER JOIN EMP_TB_TRAN_PROBATION_REVIEW_FROM_ANSWERS RA 
                       ON QO.ID = RA.QUESTIONID 
               INNER JOIN EMP_TB_TRAN_PROBATION_REVIEW_REVIEWER R 
                       ON R.REVIEWERID = RA.REVIEWERID)T
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct` to remove duplicate rows

```
SELECT distinct ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY QUESID DESC)                     AS RowNum, 
       QUESID, 
       QUESCATEGORY, 
       QUESTION, 
       ID                                            OptionID, 
       OPTION_NAMES, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), ISNULL(RA.REVIEWERID, ''))ReviewerID, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), ISNULL(ANSWER, ''))       Answer 
FROM   EMP_TB_APP_QUESTIONMASTER QM 
       INNER JOIN EMP_TB_EOB_QUESTIONBANK_OBJECTIVEOPTIONS QO 
               ON QM.QUESID = QO.QUESTIONID 
       INNER JOIN EMP_TB_TRAN_PROBATION_REVIEW_FROM_ANSWERS RA 
               ON QO.ID = RA.QUESTIONID 
       INNER JOIN EMP_TB_TRAN_PROBATION_REVIEW_REVIEWER R 
               ON R.REVIEWERID = RA.REVIEWERID
```

Comment: Just adding DISTINCT won't help, since the row_number will give identical rows different numbers and the distinct will not remove them.